# JQuery Datatable PageLength Not Working

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a function that gets data from a REST API and then adds the results to a datatable like so. The problem is that the resulting table shows all the results on one page instead of breaking it into pages of 50.

```
$('#SearchResults').remove(); //clear previous results

$.getJSON(link, null, function (data) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    if (data.value.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById('notFound').innerHTML = "Search returned no results. Please check your selections and try again.";
    } else {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.id = "SearchResults"
        $("#SearchResults").attr('data-page-length', 50);
        $("#SearchResults").attr('data-order', '[[ 1, "asc" ]]');

        var head = document.createElement('thead');

        $.each(data.value, function (i, value) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(value));
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            var td1 = document.createElement('td');
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');

            var link = "<a href=property.html?accountID=" + value.accountID + "/>";

            td1.innerHTML = link + value.accountID;
            td2.innerHTML = link + value.address;
            td3.innerHTML = link + value.fair_value;

            tr.appendChild(td1);
            tr.appendChild(td2);
            tr.appendChild(td3);

            //table.appendChild(tr);
            head.appendChild(tr);
        })
        table.appendChild(head);
        document.body.appendChild(table);
        $('#SearchResults').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "searching": false,
            "pageLength": 50
        });
    }
});
```

On the html page I am including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Again, the problem is that the table is displaying all the results from the REST call one page instead of breaking it into pages of 50.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to build the tale as datatable from scratch instead of building it as html then converting it to a datatable.